# How to filter out unique tags and store in an array from object given below using hooks

Tags: reactjs, json, use-state, fetching-strategy

```
export const imageTag = [
```

{
link:
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/70069/pexels-photo-70069.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-daniyal-ghanavati-70069.jpg&fm=jpg",
id: 1,
title: "Bird image",
tags: ["nature", "bird"]
},
{
link:
"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/renewable-energy-and-sustainable-development-picture-id1186330948?k=20&m=1186330948&s=612x612&w=0&h=5aNPCcQ8FcZraX44PEhb2mqcHkow2xMITJMHdh28xNg=",
id: 2,
title: "nature 1",
tags: ["nature"]
},
{
link:
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538941214074-9b578e573632?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Nnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80",
id: 3,
title: "river image",
tags: ["nature", "river"]
},
{
link:
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/459198/pexels-photo-459198.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-459198.jpg&fm=jpg",
id: 4,
title: "image river-nature",
tags: ["nature", "river"]
},
{
link:
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1001682/pexels-photo-1001682.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kellie-churchman-1001682.jpg&fm=jpg",
id: 5,
title: "image12",
tags: ["sea"]
},
{
link:
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Wildlife_at_Maasai_Mara_%28Lion%29.jpg/800px-Wildlife_at_Maasai_Mara_%28Lion%29.jpg",
id: 6,
title: "Animal 1",
tags: ["animal"]
},
{
link:
"https://res.cloudinary.com/dk-find-out/image/upload/q_80,w_1920,f_auto/Animal_kingdom_nzwbda.jpg",
id: 7,
title: "Animal 2",
tags: ["animal"]
},
{
link:
"https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/side-view-lion-walking-panthera-260nw-165448391.jpg",
id: 8,
title: "lion 2",
tags: ["lion"]
},
{
link:
"https://images.pexels.com/photos/1172253/pexels-photo-1172253.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
id: 9,
title: "lifestyle image",
tags: ["lifestyle", "river"]
},
{
link:
"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569__480.jpg",
id: 10,
title: "galaxy 1",
tags: ["galaxy"]
},
{
link:
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8bGVuc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80",
id: 11,
title: "Lens",
tags: ["lens"]
},
{
link:
"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__480.jpg",
id: 12,
title: "image flower",
tags: ["nature", "flower"]
}
];

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, your question is badly formatted and there is not enough details to help people understand what you want. please format the code and add a description of the goal, the problem and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is one approach.

```js
const data = [{ link: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/70069/pexels-photo-70069.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-daniyal-ghanavati-70069.jpg&fm=jpg", id: 1, title: "Bird image", tags: ["nature", "bird"] }, { link: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/renewable-energy-and-sustainable-development-picture-id1186330948?k=20&m=1186330948&s=612x612&w=0&h=5aNPCcQ8FcZraX44PEhb2mqcHkow2xMITJMHdh28xNg=", id: 2, title: "nature 1", tags: ["nature"] }, { link: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538941214074-9b578e573632?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Nnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80", id: 3, title: "river image", tags: ["nature", "river"] }, { link: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/459198/pexels-photo-459198.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-459198.jpg&fm=jpg", id: 4, title: "image river-nature", tags: ["nature", "river"] }, { link: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1001682/pexels-photo-1001682.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-kellie-churchman-1001682.jpg&fm=jpg", id: 5, title: "image12", tags: ["sea"] }, { link: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Wildlife_at_Maasai_Mara_%28Lion%29.jpg/800px-Wildlife_at_Maasai_Mara_%28Lion%29.jpg", id: 6, title: "Animal 1", tags: ["animal"] }, { link: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dk-find-out/image/upload/q_80,w_1920,f_auto/Animal_kingdom_nzwbda.jpg", id: 7, title: "Animal 2", tags: ["animal"] }, { link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/side-view-lion-walking-panthera-260nw-165448391.jpg", id: 8, title: "lion 2", tags: ["lion"] }, { link: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1172253/pexels-photo-1172253.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500", id: 9, title: "lifestyle image", tags: ["lifestyle", "river"] }, { link: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569__480.jpg", id: 10, title: "galaxy 1", tags: ["galaxy"] }, { link: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8bGVuc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80", id: 11, title: "Lens", tags: ["lens"] }, { link: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__480.jpg", id: 12, title: "image flower", tags: ["nature", "flower"] } ]

const allTags = []
data.forEach(item => {
  const {tags} = item
  allTags.push(...tags)
})
const filtered = [...new Set(allTags)].sort()
console.log(filtered)
```